# Add field to contact lookup \ create New window

Tags: administration, customization, fields

When entering a new case, employees need to search for a contact, simple enough. 
When they can't find the contact, they add a new one by pressing the New button from the lookup window, still simple.
When they are entering the new contact, there are a few fields that are missing that I need to place in there...apparently not simple for me. Where is this form and how can I edit the fields that are displayed when a user is entering a new contact?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This New button is enabled in the lookup dialogs if only quick create is enabled in your organization. But i think this is the recent change that this option is enabled by default after summer 13. 
Also this actually cant be modified and also not recommed to use since it bypass the validation rules and also bypass the required fields too. 
If u want such functionality go with the custom VF page and override the loopup dialog completely

Hope this helps

Comment: Agreed; the Quick Create option is Bad.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mukulgoel has mentioned, custom VF page is the way to go. If you are looking at how to do it. You can refer to these links

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/
and
http://sfdchack.blogspot.in/2013/01/salesforce-custom-lookup-using-apex.html